# too slow alter index reorganize/rebuild (with online)

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I have 2 similar SQL Server installations on 2 similar GCP projects.
Everything is the same - configuration, CPU, RAM, disk drive layout, similar (but not the same) database with similar data and workload.

When I run `alter index index [IndexName] on dbo.Tablename rebuild with (online=on)` on the 1st server it takes about 30 minutes to rebuild the whole index. On the 2nd server it ran for more than 3.5 hours before I stopped the rebuild.

All disk metrics (throughput, queue length, etc.) look reasonable. The rebuild is being performed during a night maintenance window with no significant transaction load on the server.

My question is: How can I "debug" the rebuild process to see what is going on, why two similar databases on two similar servers act very different? Is there any trace flag, extended event, etc. which may help to investigate the problem?

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64) 
    Mar 18 2018 09:11:49 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
26CPU/20GB of RAM

Index size before rebuilding: ~110Gb, after rebuilding: ~30Gb

Comment: [How Using NOLOCK Can Block Your Queries](https://hackernoon.com/how-using-nolock-can-block-your-queries-adc8611105ff) - WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY

Comment: You could always run sp_whoisactive to see what is going on the SQL Server instance during rebuild(see blocking queries, wait locs, ...)

Comment: sp_who/similar sps shows no noticeable processes/locks, server dashboard shows few waits (writelog/hadr), but nothing serious

Comment: also we do not use nolock except in non-frequent alert queries, which anyway does not run against table/index under investigation

Comment: Did you find out the reason?

Comment: No, still have no idea